# Add date column vba

Tags: excel, vba, time

I'm looking to find a way to automatically add a current date column for once I have pasted my selected data into the worksheet. My current VBA code takes the end of day trading data, embeds into the body of an email and attaches it as an excel file before sending out to the relevant groups. I would like the VBA to be able to add a date column to the active worksheet once I run the macro. The code is as follows:

```
Sub Mail_Sheet_Outlook_Body()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = False
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Set rng = Nothing
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    'You can also use a sheet name
    'Set rng = Sheets("YourSheet").UsedRange

    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .to = "Nabil.Hure@dnb.no"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "Today's Trades" & Date
        .HTMLBody = RangetoHTML(rng)
        .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        .Send                                    'or use .Display
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0

    With Application
        .EnableEvents = True
        .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With

    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
End Sub

Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Any advice on how to do this, or where to put this in my current VBA code will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add the current date/time to a range of cells in the Active Worksheet, you can use this code:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(TopCornerCell, BottomCornerCell).Value = Now()
```

For just the date (and not the time), you can use this:

```
ActiveSheet.Range(TopCornerCell, BottomCornerCell).Value = Int(Now())
```

Working out what `TopCornerCell` and `BottomCornerCell` are will depend on your requirement and data.

Finally, you can change the formatting of a range with `Range.NumberFormat` and auto-fit column width with `Range.EntireColumn.Autofit`

Answer (score 0):

As you're holding the `UsedRange` in the `rng` variable you can add a couple of lines after `Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange`:

```
Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
rng.Offset(, rng.Columns.Count).Resize(, 1) = Date
Set rng = rng.Resize(, rng.Columns.Count + 1)
```

The second line sets a reference to the column next to your range and fills it with todays date.
The last line then adds the new column to the `rng` variable.  You could use `UsedRange` again but in testing I found this not reliable - generally best not to use `UsedRange` at all.

To find the last cell without using `UsedRange` you can use `FIND` to find the last non-empty cell.

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", LastCell(ActiveSheet))
    '...
    '...
    '...

End Sub

Public Function LastCell(wrkSht As Worksheet) As Range

    Dim lLastCol As Long, lLastRow As Long

    On Error Resume Next

    With wrkSht
        lLastCol = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByColumns, xlPrevious).Column
        lLastRow = .Cells.Find("*", , , , xlByRows, xlPrevious).Row


        If lLastCol = 0 Then lLastCol = 1
        If lLastRow = 0 Then lLastRow = 1

        Set LastCell = wrkSht.Cells(lLastRow, lLastCol)
    End With

    On Error GoTo 0

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, this has worked, however the date column exceeds the number of rows I am using for the other columns, so essentially I've got excess date cells for empty rows. Do you know anyway to work around this? Ideally I would like to rows of date cells to match exactly with the number of cells in my worksheet which contain data

Comment: Good stuff.  I think the problem you may have been having is due to using `UsedRange`.  I'll add to the answer one of the ways to find the last cell without using `UsedRange`.